# select top 700 * from objectaer work only in sqlserver 2005 but 2008

Tags: ms-access, oledb

how can I select the last 700 entry in my access databse?
I'm using this

```
    private string strsqlcommandBeta = "select top 700 * from objectaer  " +
    " order by objectdate desc" +
    "  ";
```

but I'm getting this error

The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

Comment: The title of your question suggests you're using SQL Server but the tags suggest otherwise. Could you clarify?

Comment: yes sorry, I'm using access, in my online server I'm running also a sqlserver 2008 and my local machine I'm running sqlserver 2005, but in my code I'm using access, the sql server 2005 and sql server 2008 in the title was a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

Typically this is a result of using a keyword as a field name in one of your tables, or as an alias in your query. If you don't "quote" the keyword-as-a-field-name with `[]` you'll get an error.

Although I can't see any keywords being used inappropriately in your query, try this:

```
SELECT TOP 700 * FROM [objectaer] ORDER BY [objectdate] DESC
```

It's also possible that the problem is not with your query, rather if `objectaer` is a query object you've created in Access that contains incorrect syntax, you're likely seeing the error for `objectaer` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try "Limit 700" at the end

```
Select * from bla bla bla Limit 700
```