# How to use the OleDbDataAdapter Fill method to only add a determined number of rows?

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I want to add rows in a DataSet, but only a specific number of rows (in order to avoid the "Too many fields defined." exception). This is what I have tried so far:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT TOP 100 FROM [" + SheetName + "]", connection);
```

Exception: The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "] LIMIT 100", connection);
```

Exception: Syntax error in FROM clause.

I also tried this that I got from another [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016658/select-top-700-from-objectaer-work-only-in-sqlserver-2005-but-2008)

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [" + SheetName + "]", connection);
```

Exception: Too many fields defined.

I have no idea what else to try, any suggestions?

Comment: Why you are trying to include square brackets"[]"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify how many rows you would like the `Fill()` method to retrieve. Here's its signature from MSDN:

```
public int Fill(
    int startRecord,
    int maxRecords,
    params DataTable[] dataTables
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5wy74x.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well, I believe you cannot solve the problem that that are too many **fields** by limiting the **rows**.

But limiting the fields can be done. The problem with your first try

```
TOP 100 FROM
```

is that the syntax is not valid. If you want to limit the fields, you need to explicitly use the columnnames like this

```
SELECT TOP 100 ColumnName1, ColumnName2, ColumnName3 from ....
```

In general, I would recommend never to use select * but always precisely the columns you need.

Comment: you are right.. it didn't solve my problem! How can I fix this?

Comment: just use 'select Columname1, Columname2 FROM [.... ' and start with 2 columnnames and see if that works. Move on from there.

Comment: Another cause might be that you have empty columnnames in your spreadsheet?

Comment: no problem, just wondering why you accepted the other answer as the correct one?

Comment: i actually was in doubt whether to accept yours or the other one, but my initial question was correctly answered by James, it wasnt my problem after all, but it was correctly answered. im srry!

Comment: It is actually indeed the answer to the question, just the question did not address your problem. Fine anyway.